# G4 Visa DS160 Photo Upload

Tags: visas, usa

I am trying to apply for a G4 visa from Kolkata, India.

On the following websites:

https://in.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/visa-employees-nato.html

It suggests that I have to upload a photo on my DS-160 application. However, when I completed the application, I did not have an option to do the same. On the confirmation page (attached), it says that my photo will be taken at ASC. But the confirmation page itself does not indicate whether or not I need to take an appointment for the same.

Upon going to the ustraveldocs (http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/index.html?firstTime=No) website and trying to schedule an appointment, I am unable to do so because G visas are exempt from this appointment.

I am confused on how to proceed from this point. Should I just go to the consulate with pictures?

Also, would anyone have any idea about how long it takes for them to process a G4 visa after having been to the consulate?

Thank you!

Comment: I was not able to find any good information for processing times for G visas. They are very uncommon, after all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the State Department seems to issue around 20,000 to 25,000 of these annually (I believe that excludes the renewals issued inside the US, but I'm not certain).  While that's nothing compared to the millions of B visas, it's enough that consular staff are well familiar with them, so I think "uncommon" is perhaps not the best word.  I suspect that the process takes no more than a couple of days in most cases, since most grounds of inadmissibility do not apply.

Comment: Is there any chance you could answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/128819/19400 based on your experience?  Thanks!

Comment: @phoog, I could not open that link. Can you provide me a new one?

Comment: @ArkadeepBandyopadhyay thanks for your interest.  The question has been closed (as off topic because it concerns immigration) and then deleted (because it was closed).  I would have preferred for it to be migrated to [Expatriates.SE], and I've [asked in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48879037#48879037) whether it is possible to undelete it and then migrate it.

Comment: @phoog - I see. In any case, I have updated this question with an answer from myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to add my experience -

There was no need to worry about a photo upload; the text which appeared on my DS160 about how the photo would be taken at the ASC did not apply to me. I simply had to appear at the consulate during the time they were open to process "specialty" visas like G4, J1, etc. Only had to submit two photos as per US visa regulations.

Got my visa in 2 days!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should bring a printed photo to the consulate with you.

The [consulate web site](https://in.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/) states, in part:

> You will upload your photo while completing the online Form DS-160. If the photo upload fails, you must bring one printed photo in the format explained in the [Photograph Requirements](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/photos.html).

Just bring the photo with you, along with your passport, DS-160 barcode page, and diplomatic note.

The consulate web site also explains that you don't need to make an appointment for a diplomatic visa. You can simply go directly to the consulate without an appointment.

> Applications for official and diplomatic travelers can be submitted by the applicants or their representatives directly at the Embassy visa gate number 6, or at any U.S. consulate in India during regular service NIV hours . . .

Comment: It is not necessary to have a diplomatic passport to get a G-4 visa.  In fact I suspect that most G-4 visa holders do not qualify for a diplomatic passport.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

So for me, I will be joining an international organization for work - and my passport is a regular passport. 

I am just thrown off by the fact that my DS160 confirmation page says that the photo will be taken at the Application Service Centre (ASC), but I can't actually make an appointment at the said ASC. I will call up the consulate tomorrow to be sure.

Comment: @ArkadeepBandyopadhyay my wife has a G-4 visa, but her initial application was so long ago that her experience is almost certainly not relevant (before the introduction of the DS-160).  I am about to meet a couple of her friends for brunch so I'll see if either of them has had recent experience.

Comment: @ArkadeepBandyopadhyay unfortunately I wasn't able to get anything useful out of brunch.